# Remove invalid value from array of ids and get out for valid ids in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, controller

I am trying build one sample ROR web application. I tried to access a set of ids from request params and fetch the result form DB for those params. My param is an array of ids. I am getting proper output. Only thing if I send some wrong values in array of ids then it is not giving output. Terminating with error which says could not find all values for those ids. I am doing all these in following way :

```
if(params[:m_id])
  @m = @man.me.find(JSON.parse ((params[:m_id]).encode!('UTF-8')))
end
```

Shall I try with `Begin Rescue` or there some other better ways.Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `where` instead of `find` if you would like to fetch records and not throw an error when one does not exist.

```
if(params[:medicine_id])
  @m = @man.me.where(id: JSON.parse((params[:m_id]).encode!('UTF-8')))
end
```

Or if you know there is only one `id`, you could add `take` to the end of the query.

```
if(params[:medicine_id])
  @m = @man.me.where(id: JSON.parse((params[:m_id]).encode!('UTF-8'))).take
end
```